# unable to join 3 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am lost in joining 3 tables. 
I have 3 tables:

- Table with Events
- Table with date range
- Table with reservation count for an event on a date

Now I want to create a timeline so that for every event I have a date range with for every day a count of reservations (or 0 if there are none).
See the [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c11a3/19/0)

Now the issue is that I can select all records from date range and events but I cannot join the reservation table together with it to select the count of reservation on that day. I need it to create a graph of last x days for an event with the reservationcount on those days.

Expected output would be that for every date (2017-01-01,2017-01-02) I have a list of events(1,2,3..) and the reservationcount on that day (or if there is no matching reservationcount record, 0)
How to do that?

```
2017-01-01  1   0
2017-01-02  1   65
2017-01-03  1   345
2017-01-04  1   0
2017-01-05  1   0
2017-01-06  1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample example there is no direct link between **Events** and **EventDate**, so if you want to attach all your events to every available date you need to have a **Cartesian Product (cross join)** between these tables.

There may or may not be a reservation on a specific date and event, so you need a **LEFT JOIN** with the reservation table.

Following query should give you the desired output.

```
SELECT SelDate,EV.EventId, ISNULL(ResCount,0) as ResCount FROM
EventDates ED
INNER JOIN Events EV ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Reservations RES ON ED.SelDate = RES.EventDate AND EV.EventId=RES.EventId
```

Or you can also write it as

```
SELECT ED.*, ISNULL(ResCount,0) as ResCount FROM
(
  SELECT SelDate, EventId
  FROM EventDates ,Events
) ED
LEFT JOIN Reservations RES ON ED.SelDate = RES.EventDate AND ED.EventId=RES.EventId
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but used the wrong outer join and missed a condition.

```
Select EventDates.SelDate,Events.EventID
  ,coalesce(Reservations.ResCount,0)
from EventDates cross join Events -- one row for each event/date
left Outer Join Reservations -- join existing reservations
on Events.EventID=Reservations.EventID
and EventDates.SelDate = Reservations.EventDate
order by Events.EventID, EventDates.SelDate
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c11a3/31)